# Why doesn't 'this' work when getting data attribute on button click?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a button click event happening when my button is clicked, but when I try to get the data attribute like this

```
this.data("name");
```

I get an error saying that

> this.data is not a function()...

however if I do it this way

```
$('#btnEditDiscount').data("name");
```

then it gets me the value.

So why doesn't work using this?

```js
$('#btnEditDiscount').click(function() {
  //alert($('#btnEditDiscount').data("name"));
  alert(this.data("name"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnEditDiscount" data-name="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</button>
```

Comment: because `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Maybe $(this) is.

Comment: `this` just returns the button element, not a jquery object.

Comment: @MarkC., but isn't a data attribute an element?

Comment: Let me say it in a different way. `element.data("name")` isn't valid. There is no native DOM API for `.data()`. `.data()` is a *jQuery* method. Aka `this` must be a jQuery object. That's why `$(this).data("name")` works and yours doesn't.

Comment: @MarkC., ahhh ok, gotcha. I understand now. Thanks

Comment: No problem - glad I could help